# Wild card pattern in Python url

Tags: python, regex, django

I am new in Django and need url pattern to match everything (particularly uuid). The question and answer may seem very simple, but I need your help here. The below is my code:

```
# parent urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('alerting/', include('alerting.urls')),
]

# alerting/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test', views.test, name='test'),
    path('.*', views.test, name='uuid'),
]
```

I've tried in many ways but could find how make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a parameter to capture:

```
path('<uuid>/', views.test, name='uuid'),
```

And retrieve this parameter in your view:

```
def test(request, uuid):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you need to specifically match uuids rather than just everything, there is a [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) for that:

```
path('<uuid:uuid>/', views.test, name='uuid'),
```

Comment: And what if I want to match everything ? like .*

Comment: Then catavaran's answer is what you want.